# Are your sins forgiven if you say astagfirullah 100 times aday without intention

Tags: sin, tawba

I read astagfirullah every day between Asr and Magrib, but most of the time I read it because I made a routine that I would read it everyday, will I still be forgiven?

Answer (score 1):

Repeating words for a long time is a meditation practice. I do not practice alike so that I can not pronounce myself thereon and I don't object to it either.
It's however not necessary for being forgiven by Allah. He promises to forgive the sins to those who believe and (try to) follow His commands and repent duly.
It's better to recognize a concrete sin and ask Him for forgiveness.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your sins will be forgiven or not (because Allah is the one who forgives your sin). But there's a hadith similiar to what you did:

"I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying." By Allah! I ask for forgiveness from Allah and turn to Him in repentance more than seventy times a day."

[Bukhari 6307](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6307) (Shahih ACCORDING to Bukhari)

Wallahu a'lam